# Setting `scroll-conservatively` to 101 causes `dired` buffer can not be recentered when revert

Tags: dired, scrolling, recenter

When I set `scroll-conservatively` to 101 as recommended from many scrolling packages. But I find that in a `dired` buffer containing many files, `revert-buffer` (`g`) will not recenter the point to center but instead to the bottom.

How to fix this?

- Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin23.2.0, Carbon Version 170 AppKit 2487.3) of 2023-12-24`

Tested in a `emacs -q` session

[image]